# Mounting a file from server to the docker container, in a way it can be accessible

Tags: docker, mount

Say, I have a docker image for a tool. Now I need to run the tool. However, the input is located in some other server/location. I need to mount this input to the docker container or make it accessible to the docker image/tool.
For example,
I activate the docker image as following,

`docker run -t -i -v $HOME/vep_data:/opt/vep/.vep ensemblorg/ensembl-vep`
Now I need to mount the input data to the `opt/vep/.vep ensemblorg`. The input is located in another server. For example my file looks like this: `user@vm-rn.i.de:/project/home/data/bank/file_02_001`
What I need is the above-mentioned file should be
in the container in order to run this.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: we had a similar situation. In our case, since we have to deal with multiple instances of the same image, we decided to avoid dealing with the image mounting folders we opted to let the "metal" to deal with it and use the mounted folder in the docker containers.

Comment: OK, I see. May I know how was it possible? for instance, When I am inside the docker container I am not able to access the mounted folder. For instance, when I do `ls`/ list of the file which is currently in the mount point, I am not able to access it from the containers

Comment: can you try mounting it with samba inside the container?

Comment: I havent tried samba inside the container

Comment: you can mount on your machine using sshfs, e.g. `sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa user@vm-rn.i.de:/project/home/data/bank/ $HOME/vep_data`. After mounting the data will be available  in your  container under the `/opt/vep/.vep` folder. EDIT: you need to install the sshfs package though...